# how to modify webpack chunks name based on browser (client) time like chunk.js?timestamp=browserTime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, browser-cache, cra

i have a react application in `webpack` setting the chunks are getting generated like

```
50b74e3a.chunk.js
```

every time its got build the hash changed by webpack but that is not useful for cache busting
in browser , there its cached the old chunk file even after chunk hash changed on server

so for that i am thinking is there a way to change

```
 50b74e3a.chunk.js
```

to

```
50b74e3a.chunk.js?timestamp=browserUserTime
```

so time should come from user's machine

by this way it will be changed by client Javacsript at loading time which means it will have to load the fresh copy from server